# How can I build the Apple APNS v2 specific OID into the CSR

Tags: ios, openssl, apple-push-notifications, csr

Apple APNS V2 introduce the "topic" concept, and assign a customized OID for it and give out an example: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1

```
Extension ( 1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.6 )
Critical NO
Data com.yourcompany.yourexampleapp
Data app
Data com.yourcompany.yourexampleapp.voip
Data voip
Data com.yourcompany.yourexampleapp.complication
Data complication
```

How can I build this extension into the CSR. I know I need to edit the openssl.conf to add it in the "req" section, but what's the specific codes to put all these attributes into CSR? The following command I try can add one line into the CSR, but how can I add the following part? Thanks in advance!!!

```
[ customized_extension ]
1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.62=Critical NO,ASN1:UTF8String:1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.62
1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.62=ASN1:UTF8String:com.yourcompany.yourexampleapp
???? --How to add the next part?

openssl req -new -sha256 -key ses_lab_20170120.key -out ses_lab_20170120.csr -config openssl.cnf 

openssl req -in ses_lab_20170120.csr -text -noout
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=CN, ST=GD, L=GZ, O=Ericsson, OU=SES, CN=test
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:b0:9e:2f:3d:52:da:71:0a:e3:93:13:2b:c4:92:
                    4b:4b:3c:0c:70:98:d5:6d:3f:a0:af:f4:03:d0:26:
                    53:6a:d4:7e:82:d7:95:6a:8f:29:eb:88:6c:67:4a:
                    94:d4:b5:ed:9a:b5:d4:e4:44:8c:1d:21:ec:ba:03:
                    df:61:3f:6a:5e:c0:ea:13:00:62:e0:df:3c:39:2b:
                    1a:2b:b0:b5:39:1a:bf:ba:d5:85:0d:37:bd:2a:92:
                    d1:6e:9b:05:37:bf:bf:c2:83:ca:8f:27:5a:b3:d3:
                    b5:53:17:7e:b0:d8:ea:ec:51:09:7f:d5:e7:5e:a5:
                    03:ff:63:28:da:11:5a:ae:10:01:05:46:da:62:02:
                    b2:20:4d:08:a8:47:ed:95:2a:b9:f3:e9:f5:e6:fb:
                    b0:29:99:c5:cf:d3:80:98:8b:8a:10:4f:8a:fa:57:
                    f8:50:31:e7:02:6a:8c:16:13:99:1d:e3:6d:ce:d5:
                    43:d9:c9:1f:50:b8:55:07:00:88:d6:ab:b1:44:46:
                    32:62:03:25:91:9a:ae:72:09:b8:a4:07:9c:86:95:
                    bf:59:0e:0e:65:73:b7:0f:86:d3:d2:7e:ac:7e:82:
                    9f:61:c8:41:b0:d6:25:2a:4f:09:93:6d:6a:15:b8:
                    60:22:ba:34:d4:69:dc:b1:6c:98:8a:4a:01:31:71:
                    b8:0f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.62: 
                ..com.yourcompany.yourexampleapp
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        62:53:2f:85:1f:7c:9f:4c:b8:48:c0:df:20:5d:3a:6d:f3:55:
        7c:63:90:66:3c:14:d5:e0:c8:4e:f3:21:2d:d8:5b:ed:4c:2d:
        38:5b:90:ad:a6:e4:0c:1d:e7:b6:c6:66:1f:41:c9:cf:f1:10:
        13:a7:27:bf:f5:74:93:76:dd:e0:1a:64:7e:66:62:87:9b:e4:
        88:c2:74:65:fc:90:04:d3:24:51:2b:c3:f0:ef:0d:b3:e9:cb:
        d8:23:d6:63:31:0a:93:d6:f3:36:99:8d:1e:33:fd:fd:c3:6d:
        a8:38:9d:63:ce:2b:2b:4e:43:93:77:87:05:e7:c5:6d:39:98:
        f2:7d:39:3e:bc:a9:9a:59:c4:ce:c2:88:ef:95:67:55:cc:a9:
        e4:3a:8a:1d:49:66:77:81:8d:0e:9b:ce:f1:cc:3d:83:62:cc:
        86:fe:4a:2d:f0:b9:70:9f:d8:75:9e:52:99:53:4e:ea:32:8d:
        af:11:9c:d3:cc:d4:8b:e5:24:c2:10:2b:11:61:52:2d:a3:67:
        f0:f6:9c:8e:3e:12:66:0f:14:9e:1c:3d:77:81:3a:26:35:e0:
        15:c5:ab:d2:4b:51:c4:2e:7d:7b:0a:92:ae:89:fb:f2:fa:32:
        81:52:da:49:16:c3:84:a9:82:e1:2d:b6:9b:03:ae:88:fb:fd:
        17:ee:3c:1b
```

Comment: Please show your code or your commands. Then, show how you use the certificate in your code.

Comment: I use the openssl command to generate the CSR: openssl req -new -sha256 -key ses_lab_20170120.key -out ses_lab_20170120.csr -config openssl.cnf. The certificate is generated by Apple certificate service and will be used for my push server to connect to the APNS. The problem is that I don't know how to build this customized extension into the CSR.